# React-Google-Login GoogleLogin component throwing Invalid cookiePolicy error

Tags: reactjs, cookies, google-api-js-client, react-google-login

I'm using React to build a simple site, and I'm testing out the GoogleLogin component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login. I run react on http://localhost:3000. I have the cookie-policy set to allow this host. However, I keep getting the same error every time I start the react server:

"Invalid cookiePolicy - gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookieP…Naq8ri2P66tzK7chsKcRiE1CsLyQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1:6"

I've also added http://localhost:3000 as an Authorized JavaScript origin in the Google OAuth credentials. In my index.js file I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleLogin
    clientId="296036318202-uraiim5u0cf5qpqhujl3aaj1kniuu41e.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
    cookiePolicy={"http://localhost:3000/"}
  />,
  document.getElementById('googleButton')
);
```

I've tried replacing the cookiePolicy with "http://localhost:3000", but then it starts complaining about cross-site cookies being sent:

"Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and I found that I was accessing the page with `http://[::1]:3000/...` instead of `localhost`.

When changed to `localhost:3000` and it worked for me.

I think google does not like `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, or using gapi in a local file since this is not secure.